# Solution verification and how to prove a function isn't integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Let $H(x)=x^2\sin(\pi/x^2)$ if $x\in]0,1]$ and $H(0)=0$. Show that $H'(x)=h(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Also, show that $H'$ is not Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$. This way, $h$ has an anti derivative in $[0,1]$ but it isn't Riemann integrable in said interval.

Finally, show that $\lim_{a\to 0+}\int_{a}^{1}h(x)dx$ exists.

---

I think I was able to prove $H'(x)=h(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$.

**My attempt:** If $x=0$ $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{H(0+a)-H(0)}{a}$$ $$=\lim_{a\to 0} a\sin(\pi/a^2)=0,$$ using $|\sin(\beta)|\leq 1$ and squeeze theorem. So, $H'(0)=0$

Now, for $x\in(0,1]$ we have that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\sin(\pi/x^2)\right)$$ $$=2x\sin(\pi/x^2)-\frac{2\pi\cos(\pi/x^2)}{x}.$$ Is my attempt correct? Does it prove what I was asked?

Also, how can I do the rest of the exercise? I honestly don't know how to prove that $H'$ isn't integrable in $[0,1]$ or that $\lim_{a\to 0+}\int_{a}^{1}h(x)dx$ exists.

Isn't the function $$h(x)=H'(x)=2x\sin(\pi/x^2)-\frac{2\pi\cos(\pi/x^2)}{x}$$ if $x\in(0,1],$ $$H'(0)=0$$ bounded?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the first part is correct (as long as the differentiation is), and as for the second part I think you should refer to the definition of Riemann integral, i.e. the lower limit is the same as the upper limit. You may fint fault with that since the second term is oscillating very fast and sharp(so yeah it's unbounded around 0 since it's something oscillating from -1 to 1 divided by a very small value). So you can see that the definition of Riemann integral goes wrong here.

Comment: That would be the definition  of riemann integral using Darboux sums, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is correct, to show that $h$ is not Riemann integrable notice that $h$ is unbounded, let $M>0$ be a real number and let $N$ be a natural number such that $N$ is odd (this implies that $N^2$ is odd) and $M<N$, then:

\begin{align*}
h(1/N) &= 2(1/N)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{(1/N)^2}\right) - \frac{2\pi\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{(1/N)^2}\right)}{1/N}\\
\\
&= \frac{2}{N}\sin(N^2\pi) - 2N\pi\cos(N^2\pi)\\
\\
&= 0 + 2N\pi > M
\end{align*}

this means that $h$ is not bounded, which implies that $h$ is not Riemann integrable. Now notice that, when $x\in [a,1]$ and $a\in (0 , 1)$, the restriction of $h$ in $[a,1]$ is continuous since is the combination of other continuous functions in $[a,1]$, this implies that the restriction is Riemann integrable in $[a,1]$ for all $a\in (0,1)$, in special you can use the fundamental theorem of Calculus in $[a,1]$ and you get that:

$$\lim_{a\to 0+} \int^{1}_{a} h = \lim_{a\to 0+} \big(H(1) - H(a)\big) =\lim_{a\to 0+} -a^2\sin(\pi/a^2) = 0$$